# Order By Percent Decreasing

Tags: sql, ms-access

Code :

```
SELECT [1_Tbl_Claim_Data].Customer, Sum([1_Tbl_Claim_Data].ClaimUSD) AS ClaimedAmount, Sum([1_Tbl_Claim_Data].POReimbursementAmountUSD) AS RmbtAmount, Format(Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)*100/Sum(ClaimUSD),"Fixed") AS ["%"]
FROM 1_Tbl_Claim_Data
GROUP BY [1_Tbl_Claim_Data].Customer
ORDER BY Format(Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)*100/Sum(ClaimUSD),"Fixed") DESC;
```

I am getting an **overflow error** when i try to order my qry by percentage expression.
The issue is that some reimbursement amounts are zero so I am guessing that is causing the overflow error, when a number is being divided by zero
Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing the data, there's not much help to give. But, could ClaimUSD ever be zero? That might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT  Customer
       ,Sum(ClaimUSD) AS ClaimedAmount 
       ,Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD) AS RmbtAmount
       ,Format(Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)*100/Sum(ClaimUSD),"Fixed") 
        AS ["%"]
FROM 1_Tbl_Claim_Data
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to test for `SUM(ClaimUSD)` being 0.

Also, do you really intend to sort by percent descending **in alphabetical order**?

```
99%
9%
81%
22%
2%
12%
100%
10%
1%
```

I assume you really want to sort by the numerical value.

```
SELECT [1_Tbl_Claim_Data].Customer
, Sum([1_Tbl_Claim_Data].ClaimUSD) AS ClaimedAmount
, Sum([1_Tbl_Claim_Data].POReimbursementAmountUSD) AS RmbtAmount
, Format(
    case
        when sum(ClaimUSD) <> 0
            then Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)*100/Sum(ClaimUSD)
    end ,"Fixed") AS ["%"]
FROM 1_Tbl_Claim_Data
GROUP BY [1_Tbl_Claim_Data].Customer
ORDER BY case
        when sum(ClaimUSD) <> 0
            then Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)*100/Sum(ClaimUSD)
    end DESC;
```

...but I would need data for testing.  There may be a number of problems with this code.

Comment: They do not have to be in alphabetical order just percent descending. Some of the rbmt amount will be zero, so I believe thats what is causing the overflow error

Comment: 0/1 = 0, so that's not causing the error.  It's more likely ClaimedAmount = 0 is causing problems.  That's what the `CASE` statement is intended to handle.  Your code attempts to sort alphabetically.  Mine sorts numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to order by the numeric value:

```sql
SELECT 
    Customer, 
    Sum(ClaimUSD) AS ClaimedAmount, 
    Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD) AS RmbtAmount, 
    Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)/Sum(ClaimUSD) AS [Percent],
    Format(Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)*100/Sum(ClaimUSD),"Fixed") AS ["%"]
FROM 
    [1_Tbl_Claim_Data]
GROUP BY 
    Customer
ORDER BY 
    Sum(POReimbursementAmountUSD)/Sum(ClaimUSD) DESC;
```